# Code snippet overflows container

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

The code snippet in [HTML horizontal image scroll not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726734/html-horizontal-image-scroll-not-working) causes the viewport to expand wildly in iOS Safari (iOS 9.1)

> [image]

Comment: What version of iOS and Safari are you running?

Comment: iOS 9.1 (char limit)

Comment: Safari 9. Safari versions always match the os version

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in either Safari on iOS 9.1 or Safari 9.0 (11601.1.56) on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Are you using the new navigation?